# Comparison between the limits of two real functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I know

1. If $f:D(\subset\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R,c$ is a limit point of $D,$ and $f(x)\ge(\text{resp.}\le)~a~\forall~x\in D-\{c\},$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f(x)\ge(\text{resp.}\le)~a.$ (*Provided the limit exists*)
2. If $f,g,h:D(\subset\mathbb R)\to \mathbb R,c$ is a limit point of $D,$ and $f(x)\le g(x)\le h(x)~\forall~x\in D-\{c\},$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}h(x)\implies \displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}h(x).$

I wounder whether the following result holds:

> $\diamond$ Let $f,g:D(\subset\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R,c$ is a limit point of $D,f(x)\ge g(x)~\forall~x\in D-\{c\}.$ Do all these imply $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f(x)\ge\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}g(x)?$ (*Provided the limits exist*)

For then it will be more powerful result from which both 1 and 2 follow.

**My Attempt:**

$F-\epsilon<f(x)<F+\epsilon~\forall~x\in D\cap N'(\delta_1)$

$G-\epsilon<g(x)<G+\epsilon~\forall~x\in D\cap N'(\delta_1)$

Set $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}.$ Then $G-\epsilon<g(x)\le f(x)<F+\epsilon~\forall~x\in D\cap N'(\delta)$ i.e. $G<F+\epsilon.$

Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary so $G\le\displaystyle\inf_{\epsilon>0}(F+\epsilon)=F.$

*Is my attempt correct?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can just use **1.** for the function $h = f - g$ and $a=0$.

Comment: ohhhhhhhh!!!! nooooooooooo........:(

Comment: So I simply need one result: $f:D\to\mathbb R$ and $c$ is a limit point od $D.$ Then $f\ge0$ on $D-\{c\}\implies\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}{f(x)}\ge0.$  Right?

Comment: @SritiMallick, yes, exactly.